# Is it possible to create a HTTP response via scapy

Tags: python, http, tcp, scapy

I want to send a HTTP response via scapy to a target system. I know scapy uses layered implementation to create a packet like IP/TCP/ETHER. To send a simple TCP packet we can use the following scapy script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

ip=IP(src="10.10.1.207", dst="10.10.1.60")

payload="Hello World"
PUSH=TCP(sport=80, dport=3389, flags="F")
send(ip/PUSH/payload)
```

---

Is there any way we can attach a HTTP layer with this?
I tried many ways however every time I receive a TCP packet instead of a HTTP response packet on the target machine.

Comment: By response packet I mean when we try to access basic information of any url we send a get request(HTTP) and in response we receive a response packet with header like " HTTP 1.1 200 OK...etc" I want to create this response packet via scapy(or any other tool) and send it to target system.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: this is outdated. Since Scapy 2.4.3 you can use [the http layer](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html)**

Scapy does not have a native HTTP layer dissector, however, you can send an HTTP request/response easily as it is a textual protocol:

```
RESP  = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
RESP += "Server: exampleServer\r\n"
RESP += "Content-Length: 6\r\n"
RESP += "\r\n"
RESP += "A body"

IP(src="10.10.1.207", dst="10.10.1.60")/TCP(sport=80, dport=3389, flags="A", seq=ACK.ack, ack=ACK.seq)/RESP
```

`ACK` is the third segment of a previously made 3 way handshake (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK) as this is necessary before sending data over TCP.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this works fine when I keep the body within 1460 bytes (i.e. header+body). Can you also suggest me a way send data of size more than 1460 bytes(in multiple packets for the same response) ? The frame is getting dropped if the size exceeds the MTU and that's fine. However is there any way to send HTTP response to the target system via scapy which is more than 1460 bytes ?

Comment: Yes, using multiple TCP segments. If I were you, I'd compute the length of my HTTP response first, divide it by my MTU, it would give me the number of necessary segments (`segments_nb = len(HTTP_resp) / MTU`, be careful with the rest of the division) and then do a loop that sends them with the rights sequence numbers. Using Scapy forces you to manually segment your data.

Answer (score 1):

Although, Scapy does not have native support for HTTP Layer but there is a python module available for extending the functionality of Scapy to  support HTTP layer. The module name is "scapy-http" and can be found on github at [invernizzi/scapy-http](https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http).

You can install it using pip:

```
    sudo pip install scapy-http
```

Here is the example code from github repository:

```
    
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    try:
        import scapy.all as scapy
    except ImportError:
        import scapy

    try:
        # This import works from the project directory
        import scapy_http.http
    except ImportError:
        # If you installed this package via pip, you just need to execute this
        from scapy.layers import http

    packets = scapy.rdpcap('example_network_traffic.pcap')
    for p in packets:
        print '=' * 78
        p.show()
```

Using this module, you can generate HTTP packets without sending your own text data.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jeff Bencteux's answer, http layer is now available on scapy. This can be easily done by this, here's an example:

```
>>>import scapy.all as S

>>>S.load_layer("http") # without this, http might not be loaded as default
>>> pkg = S.IP() / S.TCP() / HTTP() / HTTPResponse(Server="exampleServer") / "<html></html>"
```

The sting at the end of the last line is raw data. Echoing `pkg` you'll get:

```
>>> pkg
<IP  frag=0 proto=tcp |<TCP  sport=http dport=http |<HTTP  |<HTTPResponse  Server='exampleServer' |<Raw  load='<html></html>' |>>>>>
```

*You should [read the doc](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.http.html)* and maybe sniff some http responses to understand which fields you need to modify