# Sending HTTP packet using scapy

Tags: python, http, scapy, packet

How would I use scapy 2.4.3+ to spoof a http response? I tried using the packet below, however on the target machine (which has been arp spoofed, where the machine of the spoofer does not have port fowarding, resulting in the http request having to be answered by the spoofed packet, that is what I am trying to do), the provided HTML from the packet does not get rendered, once its sent using `scapy.send(packet)`. So how would I adapt the packet below, to send a HTTP packet that would render on the target machine?

```
packet = scapy.IP(src=server_ip, dst=target_ip)/scapy.TCP() / HTTP() / HTTPResponse(Server=server_ip) / "<html><p>Hi</p></html>"
```

Comment: There are outdates answers found in this thread https://python-forum.io/thread-14620.html, what Im trying to do with this question is to get a updated answer, as scapy 2.4.3+ versions have support

Comment: The incomplete answer to a previous users question, which I inspired the script in the question is found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62973402